# How can I install Eclipse on Fedora 37?

Tags: eclipse, installation, fedora, flatpak

I have been trying to install Eclipse on Fedora 37.

I tried the following instruction:

"flatpak install org.eclipse.Java"

I expected to see download in progress, but instead I keep getting the following result:

"error: No remote refs found for ‘org.eclipse.java’"

Answer (score 2):

You missed the remote `flathub` in `flatpak install <remote> org.eclipse.Java`:

[`flatpak install flathub org.eclipse.Java`](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.eclipse.Java)

(assuming you have configured `flathub` via [`flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo`](https://flatpak.org/setup/Fedora) before).